# Get difference between two strings where characters are separated by '.'?

Tags: javascript, string, diff

I would like to get the difference between two strings I have the following code:

```
var stringA = phonemes[i] // S.EY.S
var stringB = phonemeObjects[i] // S.AY.Z

const getDiff = (string, diffBy) => string.split(diffBy).join('.')

const stringC = getDiff(stringA, stringB)

console.log(stringC)
```

At the moment the above code returns the input string as the output but what I would like to be able to do is specify that the characters within the strings are separated by a '.' for instance if I was to compare S.EY.S with S.AY.Z the return would be A.S since the difference between the two is this.

I would like to mention that not all strings are similar to each other when I compare them, sometimes the strings are vastly different for example F.EY.L and K.AE.T. the only thing that the strings have in common is that each character is separated by a period/fullstop "."

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Of course stringC is the same as stringA, the `string.split` function won't do anything if stringB isn't a substring of stringA

Comment: Please elaborate  this => **if I was to compare S.EY.S with S.AY.Z the return would be A.S since the difference between the two is this** how ?

Comment: yeah, shouldn't it be E and S, or A and Z ?